# ICS without the default DHCP server

Tags: windows-7, lan, dhcp

Using windows 7, Is it possible to turn on Internet Connection Sharing but rather than using the built in dhcp provided by windows, I want to use my own app to handle that. Is there a way to turn off the provided dhcp server.

Answer (score 0):

You can un-check the "Automatically Configure IP" option on clients so that they do not receive the DHCP lease and assume IPs that are specified in the IP configuration page. But I am not sure how they will identify which client is hosting the network that is sharing the internet connection.